# Relation does not exist issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration

I am running into an issue when migrating the db

```
class CreateBlogoTaggings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    taggings_table = "#{Blogo.table_name_prefix}taggings"

    create_table(taggings_table) do |t|
      t.integer :post_id, null: false
      t.integer :tag_id , null: false
    end

    add_index taggings_table, :tag_id, unique: true
    add_index taggings_table, :post_id, unique: true

    if defined?(Foreigner)
      tags_table  = "#{Blogo.table_name_prefix}tags"
      posts_table = "#{Blogo.table_name_prefix}posts"

      add_foreign_key taggings_table, tags_table , column: :tag_id
      add_foreign_key taggings_table, posts_table, column: :post_id
    end
  end
end
```

Migrating that gives me

```
== 20180215114117 CreateBlogoTaggings: migrating ==============================
-- create_table("blogo_taggings")
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "posts" does not exist
: CREATE TABLE "blogo_taggings" ("id" serial primary key, "post_id" integer NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT fk_blogo_taggings_post_id FOREIGN KEY ("tpost_id") REFERENCES "posts" ("id"))
```

I have even commented everything inside `change` below the `create_table` method and it still gives the same error.

Can you tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have a `Post` model in your app?

Comment: do you have posts table in database?

Comment: @Muaad no but I have blogo_post table

Comment: @Raaz That is the issue. It is expecting a `posts` table probably backed by a `Post` model. Try editing the `CreateBlogoTaggings` migration file. Replace all occurrences of `post_id` with `blogo_post_id` and run the migration again.

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy why would that matter? If I comment the code below the create_table method, is nt it just creating columns in the table??

Comment: @Muaad I am so confused. Suppose I comment out all the codes below the create_table method. If I run migrations again, it will give the same error. Isnt that code just creating columns inside the table?

Comment: @Raaz Yes. It is just adding columns to the table. Am not sure why it is still giving the same error. I think you have generated this migration in a wrong way. What command did you use to generate this migration?

Comment: @Muaad rake db:migrate

Comment: @Raaz I meant the command you used to generate the migration file i.e. `rails g migration ....`. Also, have you tried my suggestion above?

Comment: @Muaad your solution works. The migrations file came when i did rails generate blogo:install

Comment: @Raaz Great. I will just add the solution as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expecting a `posts` table probably backed by a `Post` model. Try editing the `CreateBlogoTaggings` migration file. Replace all occurrences of `post_id` with `blogo_post_id` and run the migration again.